# material-ui data grid pagination not working on double clicks due to using react-grid-layout library for resizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-grid-layout

i am using react-grid-layout library to resize charts and material-ui data grid table. The issue is when i click on table pagination next to the arrow it doesn't work i have to click double in speed then it works. The issue is on first click the library think i am going to drag and drop the table or maybe resize it. How i can fix this issue? Look at the attached screenshot.
[image]

this is code sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/customizable-react-dashboard-with-chart-fork-forked-rkq93e?file=/src/Content.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation everything inside `<ResonsiveGridLayout>` is draggable. You can disable dragging in a specific areas using `draggableCancel` prop from [react-grid-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout#features). It requires a CSS selector to work.

So in your case go to `Table.js` file and create a className for `pagination`. Something like this

```
<DataGrid
    componentsProps={{
      pagination: {
        className: "disable-dragging-me"
      }
    }}
  />
```

Now you use `draggableCancel` in the `<Resposive/>` component of `react-grid-layout`. Make this change in the `Content.js` file

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
    draggableCancel=".disable-dragging-me"
  >
```

Comment: Thanks its working now. This is fixed code incase if someone face same issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/customizable-react-dashboard-with-chart-fork-forked-rkq93e?file=/src/Content.js